# React state doesn't get updated using produce

Tags: reactjs, react-state, immer.js

I have a complex state `calculationResults` as

```
export interface ICalculationResult {
hw: IHwCalculationResult;
}

export interface IHwCalculationResult {
header: IHwCalculationResultHeader;
agreements: IAgreementItem[];
}

export interface IAgreementItem {   
agreementRows: IAgreementRow[];
}
```

I want to remove the agreements pertaining to a product from the `calculationResults.hw.agreements` and then push the `agreements` received from the api.

I'm using immer since the object has many properties and the record count will be more than 5000

```
 const nextState = produce(calculatedResults,(draftstate: any) =>{
      if(allsite == "1"){      
        var indices: any = [];            
        draftstate.hw.agreements.forEach(function(value:any,pos: number){
          if(value.boQItem.id == productNo)
          {
            indices.push(pos);
          }
        });
          for(var index = indices.length-1;index>=0;index--)
          {
            draftstate.hw.agreements.splice(indices[index],1);
          }   
          draftstate.hw.agreements.push(...data.hw.agreements);   
        
        }
    });
```

Do I need to set the state as `setCalculationResults(newState)`? But when I do it, there's a compiler error that newState is incompatible for `calculationResults`

Comment: Do it like this. `setCalculationResults(produce((draft) => {....})`. Here you can make changes to draft directly. You can follow this example to understand how you can use immer with react. [React & Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/example-setstate)

Comment: @Mohammed Nouman Rafique I modified the code to as suggested. But I get error, cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hw')

Answer (score 0):

As per @Muhammad Nouman Rafique, I tired using `producer` inside `setCalculationResults` but that threw the error `cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'hw')`.
In this scenario the produce method is not able to find the initial state for the draft to take. Hence it is becoming null and threw the error.
The syntax seems changed than what the documentation says. So here is how I could update the state immutably.

```
 setCalculationResults(produce(draft =>{},calculationResults));
```

So my overall code looks like below,

```
if(allsite == "1"){  
setCalculationResults(produce((draftstate: any) =>{              
var indices: any = [];            
draftstate.hw.agreements.forEach(function(value:any,pos: number){
   if(value.boQItem.id == productNo)
   {
   indices.push(pos);
   }
  });
  for(var index = indices.length-1;index>=0;index--)
  {                
   draftstate.hw.agreements.splice(indices[index],1);
  }              
   draftstate.hw.agreements.push(...data.hw.agreements);            
  },calculationResults));
}
```